# How do I detect a wool block with a color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been having trouble with this command. I am trying to detect wool with a certain color but whenever I try to detect the wool it says

```
Failed to execute '0 /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~
```

I have done a lot of research to fix this and I cant find a way to make it work. This is the command I used.

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=test] ~ ~ ~ detect minecraft:wool 1 0 /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~
```

I also used

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=test] ~ ~ ~ detect wool 1 0 /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [minecraft wiki page on commands (describing the execute detect command)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute), the correct syntax for your command:

```
execute <entity> <x y z> detect <x y z> <block> <data> command...
```

Since I suspect you mean detect a wool block in the armor stand, the XYZ coordinates for after detect would just be ~ ~ ~

As for the color of the wool, look at the [data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Wool.2C_Stained_Clay.2C_Stained_Glass_and_Carpet) page and replace  with the data value of the color you want

So your command:

```
Execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=test] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ wool <datavalue> /summon ArmorStand
```

Comment: @RockenZombi mark it as the acceptable answer if this answered your question

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell Minecraft where to test for the wool do you want to test under his feet? Above him? 800 blocks on the Z coords?
Try this:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=test] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:wool 1 0 /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: This adds nothing that the existing answer didn't already state. Duplicate answers are frowned upon and may be subject to deletion. Also, there is still an error in your command, in that your execute has one argument too many at the end (after the block and data value).